# creating a table with reference to a non primary key column

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-key-relationship

I have two tables Users & Stores

Users table primary key is combination of address & phone number (users enroll through a web page and I don't want the same user to enroll twice), the userId column is serial but not a primary key

In Stores table the column of ownerID is it's userID from the users table - but since it's not primary key the reference can not be set (although it's serial)

how can I achieve this result?

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to achieve but **combination of address & phone number as primary key** is not a good idea!

Comment: If you have a UserId in your table then I would suggest you to make that as a primary key as that would be better!

Comment: @RahulTripathi placing the key on a serial column doesn't validate duplication of users, placing it on the columns that count will eliminate duplication on insert

Comment: May I am not getting it correctly but what I meant was to say that you can create UserId as primary key. If UserId is primary key then that would be unique and will also help you to remove duplication.(Although a rare scenario but what if two users share same address and phone number?)

Comment: Address and phone number make a bad PK because they can often identify several people (consider a family with a landline or a business with several employees). You'll run into problems even if you add a UNIQUE constraint on address and phone number.

Answer (score 2):

Referenced column need not to be a primary key.
A foreign key can reference columns that either are **a primary key OR a unique constraint**.

This can be done in this way:

```
CREATE TABLE Users(
  address varchar(100),
  phone_number varchar(20),
  userid serial,
  constraint pk primary key (address, phone_number ),
  constraint userid_unq unique (userid)
);

create table Stores(
  storeid int primary key,
  ownerID integer,
  constraint b_fk foreign key (ownerID)
    references Users(userid)
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should make userid primary key, so you could reference it easily in foreign keys. To eliminate duplication of phone and address, you can define a unique constraint or unique index for those columns.